# Change date format in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am getting date format like this `/Date(1497683045200)/`. 
 I want to convert it as `dd/MM/yyyy`. I tried this

```
 <td>{{data.From |  date:'MM/dd/yyyy' }}</td>
```

But format is not changed.Any suggestion?

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/fCy5WDLKUwChMnRPsdY5?p=preview

Comment: @selvassn I tried this format but,I dint get the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a custom filter like this

```
.filter('jsonDate',function(){
  return function(date){
    return new Date(date.match(/\d+/)[0] * 1);
  }
})
```

call it like this

```
<td>{{data.From |  jsonDate |  date:'MM/dd/yyyy'}}</td>
```

Comment: thanks. But am getting like this `"2017-06-18T18:30:00.000Z"` can I use `dd/MM/yyyy` filter after `jsonDate`

Comment: @user7397787 use it like this `<td>{{data.From |  jsonDate |  date:'MM/dd/yyyy'}}</td>`

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
formatDate(date) {
        let d = new Date(date),
            month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
            day = '' + d.getDate(),
            year = d.getFullYear();
        if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
        if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;
        return [ month, day, year].join('/');
    }
```

Call that custom method on HTML

```
<td>{{formatDate(data.From)}}</td>
```